# windows terminal shortcut can't run command

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

I'm trying to create a terminal helper with a windows terminal. I've created a shortcut with following target:

```
wt ; new-tab -p "Server" -d D:\e\server python manage.py runserver; new-tab -p "Front" -d D:\e\frontend yarn start; new-tab -p "Electron" -d D:\e\ele yarn start;
```

Here `server` folder contains *django* backend, and another two contain front and electron code. That's why I'm trying to run `python manage.py runserver` and `yarn start` into two.

But what I'm getting is

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

[process exited with code 9009]
```

And(the message below twice)

```
[error 0x80070002 when launching `yarn start']
```

But when I navigate there, I get to run the command without any error.

And another important thing is, it's creating 5 instances of PS in the windows terminal.

System Information:

```
Python 3.9.7
yarn 1.22.15
node v14.18.0
PS Version 5.1.19041.1320
windows terminal 1.11.2921.0
```

Comment: What version of Python do you have installed.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score -1):

As the error messages suggests it can't find a python installation.

I would assume you have python installed?
If not just follow the suggestion and install it from the Microsoft Store.

However if you have it already installed you might want to check if you can run python from the command line. If this fails you have to add the folder where your python binaries are located to you PATH environment variable and try again.